# I need a regex that extracts ID from below pattern.. matches pattern.. [any string

Tags: cron, quartz

I need cron expression For every 90 seconds i.e. to run after every 1.5minutes

I tries * * * ? * * sleep 90; but it says Illegal character for this position: 'SLE'

Comment: Hello, your question title mentions pattern matching, but the question text is about cron expressions. Is the title accurate?

What scheduler are you using? Judging by the six fields in the expression, and the error message, it's not classic cron, right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context you're running the job in, but the error is pretty clear: the cron config arguments aren't set up correctly.

From the first link below, these are some examples:

```
# backup using the rsbu program to the internal 4TB HDD and then 4TB external
01 01 * * * /usr/local/bin/rsbu -vbd1 ; /usr/local/bin/rsbu -vbd2

# Set the hardware clock to keep it in sync with the more accurate system clock
03 05 * * * /sbin/hwclock --systohc

# Perform monthly updates on the first of the month
# 25 04 1 * * /usr/bin/dnf -y update
```

There is an immense amount of documentation and how-to's online for cron. Here are some I found:

- https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

There are also free web tools that can help you come up with the perfect configuration:

- https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html
- https://crontab.cronhub.io/

This is just a small sample from a quick google for `cron` or `how to use cron`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quartz scheduler, probably the easiest would be to use two separate cron expressions:

```
0 0/3 * * * ?
```

and

```
30 1/3 * * * ?
```

The first expression fires every 3 minutes:

- 00:00:00
- 00:03:00
- 00:06:00
- 00:09:00
- ...

The second expression also fires every 3 minutes, but with a 1 minute 30 second offset:

- 00:01:30
- 00:04:30
- 00:07:30
- ...

If you combine the execution times of both, you get 90 second intervals:

- 00:00:00
- 00:01:30
- 00:03:00
- 00:04:30
- 00:06:00
- 00:07:30
- 00:09:00